# Android - Show an app chooser of all of the installed apps

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-listview

I want to open an app chooser that will list of the installed apps on the phone. When clicking on an app in the chooser I don't need to open it but get it's package name.

I know that I can create a specific intent for example with Intent.ACTION_SEND and the

```
Intent.createChooser()
```

I also know that I can list the installed packages using the package manager.

Is there a way to combine the 2 methods and create an app chooser with all of the installed apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Chooser.java**

```
public class Chooser extends ListActivity {
      AppAdapter adapter=null;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chooser_layout);

        PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
        Intent main=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

        main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);
        Collections.sort(launchables,
                         new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

        adapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,
                                     int position, long id) {

        ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
        ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
        ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                             activity.name);

        /* SetResult 

        String pack_name = name.getPackageName();

        Intent intentMessage=new Intent();
        intentMessage.putExtra("MESSAGE_package_name", pack_name);
        setResult(1,intentMessage);
        finish();

        */




      }

      class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {
        private PackageManager pm=null;

        AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
          super(Chooser.this, R.layout.row, apps);
          this.pm=pm;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                              ViewGroup parent) {
          if (convertView==null) {
            convertView=newView(parent);
          }

          bindView(position, convertView);

          return(convertView);
        }

        private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
          return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
        }

        private void bindView(int position, View row) {
          TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

          label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));

          ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

          icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
        }
      }


    }
```

**chooser_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ListView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="2px"
    android:paddingTop="3px"
    android:paddingBottom="3px"
    android:paddingRight="3px"
  />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Test App will here bla bla"
    android:paddingTop="2px"
    android:paddingBottom="2px"
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**You can choose app like this:**

```
Intent appIntent;
...

appIntent=new Intent(this,Chooser.class);
            startActivityForResult(appIntent, 1);



...


 @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
     {

       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if(null!=data){

         if(requestCode==1){
            //Do something
           String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE_package_name");
           package_Name.SetText(message);
         }
     }
```

**This will work for you.**

Answer (score 1):

Use the results of `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to populate your own UI that lists them. [This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) loads them into a `ListView`.

While that sample application turns around and launches the selected activity in `onListItemClick()`, you could do something else instead.

Comment: This will obviously work, but it does not take advantage of the built-in nicely styled app chooser of the OS. It seems a waste of time to try and design a nice ListView UI with the icons, 2 columns etc'...

Comment: @Yuval: You are welcome to find some of those resources in your SDK platform, copy them into your project, and reuse them (subject to the Apache License). There is no built-in chooser that simply tells you the chosen activity, to the best of my knowledge. The UI you are seeing is an activity that appears with `ACTION_CHOOSER`, not some utility dialog that runs in your own process.

Comment: How can I find the xml and the adapters used in Intent.createChooser()?